# How to play sound continuously using NotificationCompat.setSound in android even when the notification tray is drawn ?

Tags: android, notifications

NotificationCompat.setSound(Uri) is used to play the ringtone once when the notification is created.

```
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
```

The above code is used to play the ringtone continuously but the ringtone is stopped when the user draws the notification tray.

My problem is I want to play the ringtone continuously even when the user draws the notification tray and the ringtone must be stopped only when the notification is cleared. Can anyone help me?

Comment: it is not possible with notifications functionality, but you can achieve it with the standalone service

Comment: You mean standalone service which handles the media player to play the sound ?

Comment: yes, like that.